# Can't control Session time in ASp MVC 4.5 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am using this to login:

```
 var f = from b in db.AdminToybias
                        where b.UserName == a.UserName
                        && b.Password == a.Password
                        select b;
                if (f.Count() >= 1)
                {
                    Session["uname"] = f.FirstOrDefault().UserName;
                    Session["pass"] = f.FirstOrDefault().Password;
                    Session["role"] = f.FirstOrDefault().Role;
```

I tried both:

```
      <sessionState timeout="1440" mode = "InProc"></sessionState>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="288000" />
</authentication>
```

But the application automatically logout user after few mins (don't know exact time). I want to get session unlimited time untill he manually logout.
I tried so many hours but failed. What can i do to achieve this?
I am using Godaddy Hosting.

Comment: Do you restart the application in those few minutes? Or does the session expire even when you don't restart?

Comment: no, i don't restart it in the mean time. @Nemanja Perovic

Comment: In Proc is a very poor choice for session management if you need to keep stuff around for any determined amount of time. In Proc means "in process", and therefore, lives and dies with the App Pool process, which can recycle for any number of reasons at any time. Use a persistent store like SQL Server, instead.

Answer (score 0):

They are different things. The Forms Authentication Timeout value sets the amount of time in minutes that the authentication cookie is set to be valid, meaning, that after value number of minutes, the cookie will expire and the user will no longer be authenticated - they will be redirected to the login page automatically-. The slidingExpiration=true value is basically saying that after every request made, the timer is reset and as long as the user makes a request within the timeout value, they will continue to be authenticated. If you set slidingExpiration=false the authentication cookie will expire after value number of minutes regardless of whether the user makes a request within the timeout value or not.

The SessionState timeout value sets the amount of time a Session State provider is required to hold data in memory (or whatever backing store is being used, SQL Server, OutOfProc, etc) for a particular session. For example, if you put an object in Session using the value in your example, this data will be removed after 30 minutes. The user may still be authenticated but the data in the Session may no longer be present. The Session Timeout value is always reset after every request.